# Prevent losing git commits when doing git force push when rebasing

Tags: git

So I am trying out the approach of not having any merge commits and always just rebasing. But the issue seems that if multiple people are working on the same branch, there is a potential of losing commits, because you have to git force push. So, what happens if you rebase and git force push, but just before that your team member pushed their commit to the same branch. Their commit gets removed. And unless that member notices that, change is lost. And even if the team member notices that, it is unclear how to re-add the lost commit?

Is there a way to add some hook to check for this and require user to do another git pull --rebase before force pushing?

Comment: Coordinate pushes on main and work in your own branches in between? GIT natively doesn't have an option to lockdown a branch, you'd have to rely on additional tools.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes it is useful to work on the same branch, to for example update all branches automatically with changes done on master branch. (Like, fixing issues breaking tests inside the branch, but not related to branch.)